# How to add a list of numbers inside a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I have this dictionary in Python:

```
{'female': [27.9, 25.74, 33.44], 'male': [33.77, 33.0, 22.705]}
```

I've been trying to find the average value of each key, or in other words, get the result value of:

```
{'female':[29,026],'male':[29,825]}
```

However I don't seem to find the right way to access and average of the list within a dictionary.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {'female': [27.9, 25.74, 33.44], 'male': [33.77, 33.0, 22.705]}

for key in a:
    avg_list = [sum(a[key]) / len(a[key])]
    a[key] = avg_list

print(a)
```

This will output:

```
{'female': [29.026666666666667], 'male': [29.825000000000003]}
```